# Actionscript 3.0: What is the difference between using the ENTER_FRAME event and a TIMER event for the update method?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im looking for some comparison between ENTER_FRAME and TIMER methods when using them for an update method. I have looked around the internet for some answers but I'm still finding it hard to understand.

Would anyone be able to help with simplifying the different between them?

Answer (score 5):

Timer events can dispatch independent of the framerate of the swf (to a point).  They can happen more often or less often than an ENTER_FRAME event, and should be used if you care about the precision of calculations as they happen between the span of time covered by ENTER_FRAME.  The most common use case for this is a physics engine, where you may want to be as precise as possible and therefore wish to perform your simulation at a rate faster than Flash's fps.

Also, timers can be useful if you want a specific action to occur after a given delay.  For example, a Timer lets you perform an action after 10 seconds easily.  You simply pass 10000 milliseconds into your Timer's constructor and then the Timer event will be dispatched 10 seconds later.  If you were to use ENTER_FRAME you would need to manually track the time elapsed on every frame update if you wanted to know when 10 seconds had passed.

ENTER_FRAME events are tied to the rendering cycle of the timeline and more or less match the framerate you've specified.  For instance, if you have a framerate of 30fps then you'll receive approximately 30 ENTER_FRAME events per second.  You may receive fewer if you have a particularly complex display list, or if your logic takes a particularly long time to execute.

Answer (score 2):

`"enterFrame"` is dispatched on every frame.

Suppose your SWF is 24fps: `"enterFrame"` will be dispatched up to 24 times every second.

`"timer"` is dispatched at a set interval.

Suppose you start a `Timer` with a delay of 50 milliseconds: `"timer"` will be dispatched up to 20 times every second.

The actual frequency of these events will depend on the host environment as well as what's going on inside your application. For example, if you have a `for` loop inside your `"timer"` handler where you're iterating over a 1,000-element array and performing some string manipulation on each element, then you'll likely get fewer `"timer"` events than if your array contained only 10 elements. Likewise, if the user's system is low on free memory, then Flash Player may have trouble executing your SWF and it might slow down the rate at which these events are dispatched.

`"enterFrame"` depends directly on the frame rate. `"timer"` depends somewhat indirectly on the frame rate.

Because you (or someone else) will invariably ask what I mean by "somewhat indirectly," here's a small AS3 app that tests both events:

```
package
{

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;

public class Test extends Sprite
{
    private var timer:Timer = null;
    private var timerEventCount:int = 0;
    private var enterFrameEventCount:int = 0;
    private var startTime:Number = 0;

    public function Test()
    {
        timer = new Timer(20, 0);
        timer.addEventListener("timer", timerHandler);
        timer.start();

        addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrameHandler);

        startTime = new Date().time;
    }

    private function timerHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        timerEventCount++;

        var timeElapsed:Number = new Date().time - startTime;

        //for (var i:int = 0; i < 4000; i++)
        //  trace("i", i);

        if (timeElapsed >= 1000) {
            // Stop timer after 1 second.
            timer.stop();

            removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrameHandler);

            trace(timerEventCount + " timer events and "
                    + enterFrameEventCount + " enterFrame events in "
                    + timeElapsed + " milliseconds.");
        }
    }

    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        enterFrameEventCount++;
    }
}

}
```

Compile at 12fps:

```
mxmlc Test.as -default-frame-rate=12
```

Output:

```
45 timer events and 12 enterFrame events in 1001 milliseconds.
```

Compile at 60fps:

```
mxmlc Test.as -default-frame-rate=60
```

Output:

```
29 timer events and 58 enterFrame events in 1010 milliseconds.
```

As you can see, a higher frame rate actually slows down the timer. I'm running this in Flash Player Debugger 10.3.181.34 (10.3); your mileage may vary.

Finally, if you uncomment the `for` loop and run it again with 60fps, you'll see what I'm talking about.

Output:

```
3 timer events and 3 enterFrame events in 1145 milliseconds.
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the issues that arise from the fact that actionscript execution is only ever run in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

ENTER_FRAME is an event that is triggered every time the render loop of the virtual machine runs and this is relative to the framerate of the movie. For example, in the Flash CS IDE if you set the framerate to 30, then from the root display object or stage, 30 ENTER_FRAME events will be fired every second.

A timer on the other hand is just that, a timer. It runs solely based on the system clock time. For example, if you set a timer with a delay of 1 millisecond, then that timer will fire one millisecond after being started, and will continue to fire once every single millisecond if you enable it. What I think camus was trying to say in his answer is that this process runs independent of the framerate. It's based solely on checking the system clock and triggering events for timers that have had the requested delay satisfied. This is verified internally by storing the system time at which the timer was started and then checking the current system time repeatedly until it is greater than or equal to the saved time PLUS the timers delay. Example:

```
timer.start() //Lets say current system time is 1000
```

Timer duration is 1000, so we need to trigger this timer when the system time is greater than or equal to 2000.

```
checkTimers() //Loops, gets the current system

//If system time is greater than or equal to 2000, trigger timer with an event
dispatchEvent(Timer.TIME, etc, etc);
```

Note that the above "code" is just pseudo code to demonstrate the basic principles of the system.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful and easy to understand!

Comment: I see you're pretty new to the site, welcome and just a tip... upvote my man! lol Don't forget to upvote useful answers theres a couple here and if you find an answer that you find the best, don't forget to click the checkmark next to it to mark it as the correct answer. Glad I could  help. :)

Answer (score 0):

ENTER_FRAME is relative to the movie's frame rate . TIMER events should be absolute.

Comment: Sorry would you be able to elaborate slightly? I kind of understand but not sure what TIMER events should be absolute means?